# Sitecore Rocks Installation seems corrupted. What to do?

Tags: sitecore-rocks, visual-studio

Having recently moved my development environment to another machine, I discovered that Sitecore Rocks no longer works as before; in particular, I cannot access the "Design Template" menu under Tasks:

(under Visual Studio 2013)
[image]

I tried installing Sitecore Rocks on a different, more recent version of Visual Studio, but the result is the same.

How can I "reset" my Sitecore Rocks installation, or otherwise solve this problem?

Comment: Have you set your connection up using `Good Old Web Service` or the `Hard Rocks Service` ?

Comment: Good Old Web Service, as I did in the past. This never lead to any issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set your Sitecore Rocks connection up using the **Hard Rock Service**:

[image: Hark Rock Service]

This will then give access to additional features and options, including the "Design Template" option:

[image: Options with Hard Rock Service]

By comparison, using the **Good Old Web Service**, the options are as follows:

[image: Options with Good Old Web Service]

The above is using Sitecore Rocks v2.1.69 and Visual Studio 2015. You mention you have set it up in the past using the *Good Old Web Service* connection without any issues. Maybe something has changed, or it was previously set up with the *Hard Rock Service* without you realising.

Comment: Correct, this did the trick. I must be imagining things, for I distinctly remember using these features with the Goold Old Web Service. The vague and generic error message I was getting when trying the Hard Rock one didn't help either.

Oh well, one more for the record.